# What exactly is a "Predefined Function"?

Tags: c, function

My textbook writes the definition of predefined function as follows :

> Predefined means that it is a function that has already been written and compiled, and linked together with our program at the time of linking.

I just can't understand what does it mean. Can you explain ? I actually a beginner in C. I've searched the terminology of compiling and linking. But this definition does not makes sense to me. 
My textbook also writes that `printf`is also a predefined function.

Comment: Which textbook? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: Why a downvote ? What's wrong with it.

Comment: There are "predefined identifiers" and "predefined macro names". These are the only uses of "predefined" in the standard. Every thing else is just "gossip". Probably get a better book (since it does not clearly define the terms it is using, a sign of bad quality).

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper Actually it's used (see my previous comment), but not in any relation with functions.

Comment: As @SouravGhosh told in the answer, these are library functions. But is the definition of library function can be given as mentioned in the book ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: @HardeyPandya: By now you should already know the book is more than bad, it is not to be trusted in any its statements. So forget it and get a correct one.

Comment: This would probably be better suited to ask on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't trust that textbook if I were you. On page 5 it says:

> C permits different forms of main statement. Following forms are
>   allowed.
>
> - main()
> - int main()
> - void main()

I'm going to stop right there. `void main()` has never been allowed in standardized C. Similarly it says:

> *NOTE:* Some authors recommend the inclusion of the statement
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> ```
>
> at the beginning of all programs that use any input/output library
>   functions. However, this is not necessary for the functions *printf*
>   and *scanf* which have been defined as a part of the C language.

It is very bad practice to rely on the implicit definitions of `printf` (or any library function for that matter.)

Which leads me to believe the authors use of "defined" is shaky at best, since "definition" and "predefined" are words that have exact meanings in the C specification.

A generous interpretation would be that the library functions are linked in via the C library either provided by the compiler or found on your system, which is usually glibc. You can always run `ldd` on a linux system to see which dynamic library is used for your program.

Comment: And `main` is strongly discouraged since C99 and listed as obsolescence feature. The part about the functions is just nonsense. **All** functions have to be declared. The standard requires a warning for implicit declarations. Is that book about K&R-C or C90? Ok, the book should be banned from any list of C books.

Comment: @uh oh somebody needs a pupper, I am beginner, so obviously I don't know right things.

Comment: @HardeyPandya no one's blaming you -- You did well to come and ask :)

Comment: @Olaf The book is titled "ANSI C". Either way, `void main()` is commonly taught in the country of origin the book is published in because they still use Turbo C on DOS there.

Comment: @Quentin "I wouldn't trust the book, if I were you."

Comment: @HardeyPandya: 1) open the window 2) grab the book 3) test the aerodynamics of the book 4) find the list of recommended C books on stack overflow **yourself** 5) Pick a book 6) turn on your brain (i.e. think for yourself when ...) 7) Read that book (or the book**s**)

Comment: @HardeyPandya It's perfectly normal to not trust the textbook as they're not perfect. I know of a $300 textbook required for a college course that's full of errors, despite being the 16th edition.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: Any book still teaching ANSI-C (aka C89/90) should be banned instantly. Beginners should start with modern C99 at least. If they encounter a project with C90 in the job, they should be able to 1) try the companiy to move on to modern times, if that is not possible, then 2) easily learn the pitfalls of mideval C.

Comment: Of course, `printf()` and `scanf()` are ***not*** "part of the language" in any sense that distinguishes them from other functions in the standard library.  Compilers generally do not know their signatures automatically, contrary to the text's assertion.

Comment: I wouldn't be bothered much about teaching C90 if it were just taught *accurately*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Well... when compiling for a hosted environment, gcc by default knows a lot of the standard functions (though not the larger ones like `printf` etc.) already and may replace them with optimised inline code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Problem is, C99 introduced some incompatibilities and added very useful features. There are good reasons to use C99/C11 and not C90 anymore, so why not move things on? Interestingly, the C community much more refuses to adopt new features than e.g. the C++ community.

Comment: @Olaf The same is true for freestanding environments too actually. Your performance may be degraded if GCC decides to use its built-in memcpy over your super duper hand-written SSE3 assembly memcpy. It's tricky to get it to *not* do that regardless of the presence of a C library.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: Just checked, yes, I confused something here. It depends on strict ISO mode and `-fno-builtin` if it might use them. Regarding the memcpy: I strongly doubt your claim is true for my projects.

Answer (score 2):

A <del>*better*</del> correct (and appropriate) term to use there would be *library functions*.

To elaborate, a library contains pre-written and compiled code. To use the code (example: functions), you need to link the library to your application and *make use of* the library code (example: call the functions). You'll get the functionality *as if the code present in library in integrated in your application*.

Read about the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) and [check the list of library functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Function-Index.html)

**Note:** not ***all*** the libraries are standard library.

Comment: Better? You men "correct". "predefined" functions is nonsense, even for _intrinsics_.

Comment: @Olaf ok, that's _better_. :)